# Getting an “Invalid argument” error when giving effects to multiple videos with FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video, concatenation

I am trying to give transition effects to multiple videos together in one command using FFMPEG. I am not able to find the issue. I have tried the command as advised at url: Merging multiple video files with ffmpeg and xfade filter

I am getting error: Invalid arguments. Please advise me the solution.

Many Thanks

Command:

```
    ffmpeg -i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_mergeSameMediaAudioVideo_1_5157.mp4 
 -i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_RmvAdVi_UntilLastSplit_2_8955.mp4 
 -i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_VideoAudioUntilMarked_InsrtSameVideo_3_7749.mp4 
 -i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_mergeSameMediaAudioVideo_3_1137.mp4 
 -i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_RmvAdVi_UntilLastSplit_4_7035.mp4 
 -i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_VideoAudioUntilMarked_InsrtExternalVideo_5_1560.mp4 
 -i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_mergeExternalMediaAudioVideo_5_3387.mp4 
 -i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_RmvAdVi_UntilLastSplit_6_5929.mp4 
 -i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_VideoAudioUntilMarked_InsrtSameVideo_7_3635.mp4 
 -i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_mergeSameMediaAudioVideo_7_2726.mp4 
 -i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_RmvAdVi_UntilLastSplit_8_6239.mp4 
 -i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_VideoAudioUntilMarked_InsrtExternalVideo_9_9862.mp4 
 -i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_mergeExternalMediaAudioVideo_9_9464.mp4 
 -i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21//SSLK006998_1535.mp4

 [0][1]xfade=transition=circleclose:duration=0.5:offset=386.1[V01];
 [V01][2]xfade=transition=distance:duration=0.5:offset=522.05[V02]; [V02][3]xfade=transition=circlecrop:duration=0.5:offset=961.22[V03]; [V03][4]xfade=transition=circlecrop:duration=0.5:offset=1347.32[V04];
 [V04][5]xfade=transition=fadegrays:duration=0.5:offset=1559.07[V05];
 [V05][6]xfade=transition=diagbl:duration=0.5:offset=2180.17[V06];
 [V06][7]xfade=transition=diagbl:duration=0.5:offset=2248.67[V07];
 [V07][8]xfade=transition=hlslice:duration=0.5:offset=2724.96[V08];
 [V08][9]xfade=transition=diagbr:duration=0.5:offset=3376.38[V09];
 [V09][10]xfade=transition=diagbr:duration=0.5:offset=3762.48[V010];
 [V010][11]xfade=transition=fadewhite:duration=0.5:offset=3936.33[V011];
 [V011][12]xfade=transition=horzopen:duration=0.5:offset=4580.17[V012];
 [V012][13]xfade=transition=horzopen:duration=0.5:offset=4648.67[V013];
 [V013][14]xfade=transition=:duration=0.5:offset=5056.74,format=yuv420p[video]; 
 [0:a][1:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A01];
 [A01][2:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A02];
 [A02][3:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A03];
 [A03][4:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A04];
 [A04][5:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A05];
 [A05][6:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A06];
 [A06][7:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A07];
 [A07][8:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A08];
 [A08][9:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A09];
 [A09][10:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A010];
 [A010][11:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A011];
 [A011][12:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A012];
 [A012][13:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A013];
 [A013][14:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[audio] -map "[video]" -map "[audio]" -movflags +faststart D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_FinalMergedFile_NotFromAction_9415.mp4
```

Command and output showing error code below: Please advise.

```
    C:\Users\dinesh>ffmpeg  -i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_mergeSameMediaAudioVideo_1_5157.mp4 -i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_RmvAdVi_UntilLastSplit_2_8955.mp4 -i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_VideoAudioUntilMarked_InsrtSameVideo_3_7749.mp4 -i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_mergeSameMediaAudioVideo_3_1137.mp4 -i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_RmvAdVi_UntilLastSplit_4_7035.mp4 -i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_VideoAudioUntilMarked_InsrtExternalVideo_5_1560.mp4 -i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_mergeExternalMediaAudioVideo_5_3387.mp4 -i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_RmvAdVi_UntilLastSplit_6_5929.mp4 -i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_VideoAudioUntilMarked_InsrtSameVideo_7_3635.mp4 -i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_mergeSameMediaAudioVideo_7_2726.mp4 -i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_RmvAdVi_UntilLastSplit_8_6239.mp4 -i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_VideoAudioUntilMarked_InsrtExternalVideo_9_9862.mp4 -i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_mergeExternalMediaAudioVideo_9_9464.mp4 -i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21//SSLK006998_1535.mp4 [0][1]xfade=transition=circleclose:duration=0.5:offset=386.1[V01];[V01][2]xfade=transition=distance:duration=0.5:offset=522.05[V02];[V02][3]xfade=transition=circlecrop:duration=0.5:offset=961.22[V03];[V03][4]xfade=transition=circlecrop:duration=0.5:offset=1347.32[V04];[V04][5]xfade=transition=fadegrays:duration=0.5:offset=1559.07[V05];[V05][6]xfade=transition=diagbl:duration=0.5:offset=2180.17[V06];[V06][7]xfade=transition=diagbl:duration=0.5:offset=2248.67[V07];[V07][8]xfade=transition=hlslice:duration=0.5:offset=2724.96[V08];[V08][9]xfade=transition=diagbr:duration=0.5:offset=3376.38[V09];[V09][10]xfade=transition=diagbr:duration=0.5:offset=3762.48[V010];[V010][11]xfade=transition=fadewhite:duration=0.5:offset=3936.33[V011];[V011][12]xfade=transition=horzopen:duration=0.5:offset=4580.17[V012];[V012][13]xfade=transition=horzopen:duration=0.5:offset=4648.67[V013];[V013][14]xfade=transition=:duration=0.5:offset=5056.74,format=yuv420p[video]; [0:a][1:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A01];[A01][2:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A02];[A02][3:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A03];[A03][4:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A04];[A04][5:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A05];[A05][6:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A06];[A06][7:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A07];[A07][8:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A08];[A08][9:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A09];[A09][10:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A010];[A010][11:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A011];[A011][12:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A012];[A012][13:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A013];[A013][14:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[audio] -map "[video]" -map "[audio]" -movflags +faststart D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_FinalMergedFile_NotFromAction_9415.mp4
ffmpeg version 2021-05-09-git-8649f5dca6-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.0 (Rev6, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-sdl2 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libgme --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-librubberband
  libavutil      57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavcodec     59.  1.100 / 59.  1.100
  libavformat    59.  0.101 / 59.  0.101
  libavdevice    59.  0.100 / 59.  0.100
  libavfilter     8.  0.101 /  8.  0.101
  libswscale      6.  0.100 /  6.  0.100
  libswresample   4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libpostproc    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_mergeSameMediaAudioVideo_1_5157.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.0.101
  Duration: 00:06:26.64, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3251 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 3056 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 189 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_RmvAdVi_UntilLastSplit_2_8955.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.0.101
  Duration: 00:02:16.56, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3545 kb/s
  Stream #1:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 3348 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #1:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 190 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #2, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_VideoAudioUntilMarked_InsrtSameVideo_3_7749.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.0.101
  Duration: 00:07:19.80, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3416 kb/s
  Stream #2:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 3220 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #2:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 189 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #3, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_mergeSameMediaAudioVideo_3_1137.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.0.101
  Duration: 00:06:26.64, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3251 kb/s
  Stream #3:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 3056 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #3:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 189 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #4, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_RmvAdVi_UntilLastSplit_4_7035.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.0.101
  Duration: 00:03:32.33, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3750 kb/s
  Stream #4:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 3554 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #4:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 189 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #5, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_VideoAudioUntilMarked_InsrtExternalVideo_5_1560.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.0.101
  Duration: 00:10:21.74, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3547 kb/s
  Stream #5:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 3351 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #5:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 189 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #6, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_mergeExternalMediaAudioVideo_5_3387.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.0.101
  Duration: 00:01:09.01, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2873 kb/s
  Stream #6:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], 2679 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #6:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 189 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #7, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_RmvAdVi_UntilLastSplit_6_5929.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.0.101
  Duration: 00:07:56.90, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3899 kb/s
  Stream #7:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 3703 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #7:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 189 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #8, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_VideoAudioUntilMarked_InsrtSameVideo_7_3635.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.0.101
  Duration: 00:10:51.96, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3816 kb/s
  Stream #8:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 3620 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #8:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 189 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #9, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_mergeSameMediaAudioVideo_7_2726.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.0.101
  Duration: 00:06:26.64, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3251 kb/s
  Stream #9:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 3056 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #9:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 189 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #10, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_RmvAdVi_UntilLastSplit_8_6239.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.0.101
  Duration: 00:02:54.44, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3809 kb/s
  Stream #10:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 3613 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #10:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 189 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #11, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_VideoAudioUntilMarked_InsrtExternalVideo_9_9862.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.0.101
  Duration: 00:10:44.43, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3472 kb/s
  Stream #11:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 3276 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #11:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 189 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #12, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21/SSLK006998_mergeExternalMediaAudioVideo_9_9464.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.0.101
  Duration: 00:01:09.01, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2873 kb/s
  Stream #12:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], 2679 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #12:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 189 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #13, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21//SSLK006998_1535.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.0.101
  Duration: 00:06:48.53, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3783 kb/s
  Stream #13:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 3588 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #13:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 189 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
[NULL @ 0000020134bf8080] Unable to find a suitable output format for '[0][1]xfade=transition=circleclose:duration=0.5:offset=386.1[V01];[V01][2]xfade=transition=distance:duration=0.5:offset=522.05[V02];[V02]
[3]xfade=transition=circlecrop:duration=0.5:offset=961.22[V03];[V03]
[4]xfade=transition=circlecrop:duration=0.5:offset=1347.32[V04];[V04]
[5]xfade=transition=fadegrays:duration=0.5:offset=1559.07[V05];[V05]
[6]xfade=transition=diagbl:duration=0.5:offset=2180.17[V06];[V06]
[7]xfade=transition=diagbl:duration=0.5:offset=2248.67[V07];[V07]
[8]xfade=transition=hlslice:duration=0.5:offset=2724.96[V08];[V08][9]xfade=transition=diagbr:duration=0.5:offset=3376.38[V09];[V09][10]xfade=transition=diagbr:duration=0.5:offset=3762.48[V010];[V010][11]xfade=transition=fadewhite:duration=0.5:offset=3936.33[V011];[V011][12]xfade=transition=horzopen:duration=0.5:offset=4580.17[V012];[V012][13]xfade=transition=horzopen:duration=0.5:offset=4648.67[V013];[V013][14]xfade=transition=:duration=0.5:offset=5056.74,format=yuv420p[video];'
[0][1]xfade=transition=circleclose:duration=0.5:offset=386.1[V01];[V01][2]xfade=transition=distance:duration=0.5:offset=522.05[V02];[V02][3]xfade=transition=circlecrop:duration=0.5:offset=961.22[V03];[V03][4]xfade=transition=circlecrop:duration=0.5:offset=1347.32[V04];[V04][5]xfade=transition=fadegrays:duration=0.5:offset=1559.07[V05];[V05][6]xfade=transition=diagbl:duration=0.5:offset=2180.17[V06];[V06][7]xfade=transition=diagbl:duration=0.5:offset=2248.67[V07];[V07][8]xfade=transition=hlslice:duration=0.5:offset=2724.96[V08];[V08][9]xfade=transition=diagbr:duration=0.5:offset=3376.38[V09];[V09][10]xfade=transition=diagbr:duration=0.5:offset=3762.48[V010];[V010][11]xfade=transition=fadewhite:duration=0.5:offset=3936.33[V011];[V011][12]xfade=transition=horzopen:duration=0.5:offset=4580.17[V012];[V012][13]xfade=transition=horzopen:duration=0.5:offset=4648.67[V013];[V013][14]xfade=transition=:duration=0.5:offset=5056.74,format=yuv420p[video];: Invalid argument
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `-filter_complex` before your filters:

```
... -i D:/ffmpeg_output/Library/2020/11/21//SSLK006998_1535.mp4 -filter_complex [0][1]xfade=transition=circleclose:duration=0.5:offset=386.1[V01]; ...
```

Without this option your [filtergraph](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtering-Introduction) is interpreted as an output file name.

Comment: Many thanks @llogan. Salute to you.